# Role of current source in comparator

Tags: current-source, comparator

I have this schematic of a quarter of the internals of an LM339 from [this site](http://home.cogeco.ca/~rpaisley4/Comparators.html)

[image: LM339 schematic]

I want to know what the purpose of the four current sources are in this circuit, and how might they be implemented?

I know current sources can be implemented as the following;

- op-amps (not useful to this particular circuit or we would end up nesting opamps within opamps within opamps);
- a JFET "constant current diode" (also unlikely, as the LM339 is bipolar);
- a BJT current source, which I believe to be the most likely candidate in this device.

What happens to the circuit if the current sources are not present, or the supply isn't able to source enough current? I've tried [simulating the circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#$+1+5.0E-6+1.6308177459886661+50+5.0+50%0AR+816+224+816+160+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Ag+672+416+672+464+0%0Ag+864+416+864+464+0%0Ag+736+592+736+624+0%0Ag+800+592+800+624+0%0Ag+928+576+928+608+0%0Ag+960+560+960+592+0%0Ai+672+224+672+288+0+3.5E-6%0Ai+768+224+768+288+0+9.999999999999999E-5%0Ai+864+224+864+288+0+3.5E-6%0Ai+960+224+960+288+0+9.999999999999999E-5%0Ad+672+288+672+352+1+0.805904783%0Ad+864+288+864+352+1+0.805904783%0Aw+816+224+768+224+0%0Aw+768+224+672+224+0%0Aw+816+224+864+224+0%0Aw+864+224+960+224+0%0Ad+608+352+672+352+1+0.805904783%0Ad+928+352+864+352+1+0.805904783%0At+928+544+960+544+0+1+-2.249876517692334+0.517872185705755+100.0%0At+800+560+928+560+0+1+-0.5157064388330108+0.0021657468727442186+100.0%0At+768+576+800+576+0+1+0.5063646907008923+0.5085304375736365+100.0%0At+768+576+736+576+0+1+0.0+0.5085304375736365+100.0%0Aw+768+576+768+544+0%0Aw+768+544+736+544+0%0Aw+736+544+736+560+0%0Aw+960+288+960+528+0%0Aw+800+560+800+368+0%0Aw+736+544+736+368+0%0AM+960+528+1136+528+0+2.5%0Ax+1048+518+1117+524+0+24+output%0At+672+352+736+352+0+-1+4.198578936813609+-0.5178390736780019+100.0%0At+624+400+672+400+0+-1+4.3+-0.4071093743872458+100.0%0Aw+672+384+672+352+0%0Aw+608+352+608+400+0%0Aw+624+400+608+400+0%0A172+608+400+400+400+0+6+4.3+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5++input%0Ax+444+393+512+399+0+24++input%0Aw+736+336+768+336+0%0Aw+768+336+768+288+0%0Aw+768+336+800+336+0%0At+864+352+800+352+0+-1+4.853155258205027+-0.3696274429874764+100.0%0At+928+400+864+400+0+-1+5.0+0.1446789949222289+100.0%0Aw+864+384+864+352+0%0Aw+928+352+928+400+0%0A172+928+496+400+496+0+6+5.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5+-input%0Aw+928+496+928+400+0%0Ax+446+492+508+498+0+24+-input%0Ao+36+2+0+35+5.0+9.765625E-5+0+-1%0Ao+45+2+0+35+5.0+9.765625E-5+1+-1%0Ao+29+2+0+34+40.0+9.765625E-5+2+-1%0A) - warning, the simulation runs very slowly and fails when you make adjustments to the input voltages, which is either a bug in the simulator or I don't understand what I'm doing (most likely the latter)

I intend to implement this circuit using discrete components for learning purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q1 and Q4 are voltage followers. The function of the 3.5-µA current sources on their emitters is simply to provide their operating current. Keeping the current constant improves their speed.

Q2 and Q3 are a differential pair, also called a "long-tailed pair". Both the differential gain and the CMRR increase with the value of the shared emitter impedance. A current source has very high equivalent impedance (ideally infinite), which is why it is used here.

Q7 is a simple common-emitter amplifier. Again, its gain is directly related to the collector load impedance, so a current source is used here for high gain.

As far as implementation, the IC designer has more flexibility than you'll have with discrete parts. Usually, a bipolar current-mirror circuit is used (similar to the Q5-Q6 pair shown above), with one "master" transistor setting a reference current used by several "slave" devices. The current sources you see are all slave devices, and the different currents are set by designing those transistors with different sizes (emitter areas). The ratio of the slave emitter area to the master emitter area determines the slave output current relative to the reference current.

Comment: Excellent answer, this gives me so many new things to read up on :)

Answer (score 3):

> I have this schematic of a quarter of the internals of an LM339 from this site

Why not go to the source and refer to the [LM-393N datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm393-n)?

The schematic you've shown incorrectly labels Q5-Q6 as a "precision voltage reference representation". It's just a current mirror, not a representation of something else.

> I intend to implement this circuit using discrete components for learning purposes.

For learning purposes, the non-current-source parts of the circuit are hard enough to get right. Just use discrete current sources. They exist! LM334 is what you need: it even looks like a transistor in its TO-92 package. Then make the rest of the circuit work.

Once it works, you can replace the 100uA current source by a current mirror. The LM334 then becomes the 100uA current reference (input) for the mirror.

Once it works, extend the current mirror to have two outputs, and use the 2nd output of the 100uA mirror in place of the 2nd LM334 set to 100uA.

Once it works, replace the two 3.5uA current sources with a single current source and a two-output current mirror, just like you did for the 100uA current.

Then convert the 100uA current mirror into a 4-output mirror with per-output resistor-settable gain factor. Configure it to provide two 100uA and two 3.5uA outputs, from a common 18.7uA input. You'll be left with just a single LM334 set to 18.7uA. The gains will be 5.3 and 1/5.3 for the 100uA and 3.5uA outputs, respectively.

Once that works, replace the LM334 with one of a variety of bipolar PTAT implementations. A basic 4-transistor current-mirror-loaded PTAT current source/reference would be fine as a starting point.

Now you're left with a comparator implementation that is all-transistor. You'll note that the current source circuitry (reference and the mirrors) take more transistors than the rest of the comparator!

You may also need some startup components to get the current source going initially. You'll get the idea from the datasheet of LM393 :)